# Why does my app restart by itself after crash

Tags: crash, ios8, restart

Ever since the first release of iOS 8 DP, I've seen strange behaviors of my app on all my testing devices running iOS 8. My app sometimes restarts itself automatically after crashes. In a particular case, the app kept crashing and restarting itself endlessly and drained the device battery rapidly which caught my attention. During the investigation of the battery consumption issue, I added some logic in the application delegate so that each time the app launches, it will append a time stamp to the NSUserDefaults, so that I can know exactly when the app launches. The experiments showed that the app did restart by itself when it crashed, however, it's not reproducible every time it crashes.

I've never read anything from any of Apple's documentations that says an app can restart by itself after a crash. I wonder if anyone have experienced similar issue in their apps. Most importantly, how to prevent the app from draining the battery if it keeps crashing and restarting by itself?

Comment: Any new info about this? I also experience an app to restart itself.

Comment: After some further investigation, I discovered that this restarting-after-crash behavior was introduced from iOS 7. So, if your app has enabled any of the following background modes: Audio, Location updates, Voip, etc, when app crashes, iOS will automatically launch the app into background. This behavior could cause some serious battery draining problem if the app falls into a crash-restart loop, I really hope iOS could introduce a watch dog to prevent apps from restarting too frequently.